# document.exeCommand('copy') not copy text to clipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I've been going round and round in circles trying to create a button to copy  text to be used for coders. The problem is, I can't seem to get document.execCommand('copy') to work anywhere except in CodePen where I have been testing it. There must be something I'm missing.

This is the link to my CodePen:
[Copy Button CodePen link](https://codepen.io/Selimas/pen/MWKxQvW?editors=1111)

Please, can someone help me. I'm losing hair over this.

```js
//////////////////////////////////// COPY BUTTON FOR <PRE> TEXT BLOCKS ///////////////////////////////////////

// Add copy button to <pre> text
var textBox = document.querySelectorAll('pre.copy-text')[0];
var copyButton = document.createElement('button');
var buttonText = document.createTextNode('');

// Insert copy button into <pre>
copyButton.appendChild(buttonText);
textBox.appendChild(copyButton, textBox.firstChild);

// Copy text to <textarea> tag to facilitate copying
var tempInput = document.createElement('textarea');
tempInput.classList.add('tempText');
textBox.parentNode.appendChild(tempInput, textBox);
tempInput.innerText = textBox.innerText;

// Copying <textarea> text to clipboard
copyButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  tempInput.focus();
  tempInput.select();
  tempInput.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand('copy');
});

// Change button state before reverting
function copyAlert(event) {
  copyButton.style.backgroundColor = '#333333';
  copyButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copied.png")';
  setTimeout(function unCopy() {
    copyButton.style.backgroundColor = '#777777';
    copyButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copy.png")';
  }, 3000);
}
copyButton.addEventListener('click', copyAlert);
```

```css
pre {
  position: relative;
}

.copy-text button {
  background-color: #666666;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copy.png');
  background-size: 70px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.copy-text button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.copy-text button:hover {
  background-color: #777777;
}

textarea.tempText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre class="copy-text">  {
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "httpMethod": "PATH",
      "name": "ProjectInstanceService",
      "children": [
        {
          "httpMethod": "PATH",
          "name": "getSchedule",
          "description": "Allows accessing Schedule APIs",
          "path": "/schedule",
          "children": [
            {
              "httpMethod": "GET",
              "name": "export",
              "description": "Exports all of the schedules in the project",
              "path": "/export",
            },
            {
              "httpMethod": "PATH",
              "name": "getBySomething",
              "description": "Get a Schedule API by query parameters",
              "path": "/instance",
            },
                ......
</pre>
```

Comment: The snippet seems to work. Where else have you tried it? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Worth noting that [`execCommand` is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Answer (score 0):

While the above code snippet did work, it only worked in certain circumstances - i.e. in CodePen or as a standalone page, but not as part of my CMS.

However, I have found a solution. Thank you to "simmer" for pointing out that `execCommand` is obsolete. While that didn't really help, it did get me looking for a completely new solution - i.e. `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`. My solution is below. Please note, though, you would usually also have to add in a permission request to the browser to access the clipboard. In this case though, the site in question runs on HTTPS and the browser is only writing to the clipboard, not reading it, so this is not necessary.

```js
    // Add copy button to <pre> tag and link text
    var textBox = document.querySelectorAll('pre.copy-text')[0];
    var copyButton = document.createElement('button');
    var buttonText = document.createTextNode('');
    var copyText = textBox.innerText;
    // Insert copy button into <pre>
    copyButton.appendChild(buttonText);
    textBox.appendChild(copyButton, textBox.firstChild);
    // Copy text to clipboard on click
    copyButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText)
        .then(() => {
          // Animate button to acknowledge copy
            copyButton.style.backgroundColor = '#333333';
            copyButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copied.png")'
            setTimeout(function unCopy() {
              copyButton.style.backgroundColor = '#777777';
              copyButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copy.png")'
            }, 3000);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          // If user is denied clipboard permissions
          alert('Not enough permissions to copy text');
        });
    });
```

```css
      /* COPY BUTTON FOR <PRE> TEXT */
      pre {
        position: relative;
      }

      .copy-text button {
        background-color: #666666;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100px;
        background-image: url('https://matillion-docs.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Icons/Text-Copy.png');
        background-size: 70px auto;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-left: 1px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .copy-text button:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      .copy-text button:hover {
        background-color: #777777;
      }

      textarea.tempText {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<pre class="copy-text">Text to be copied.</pre>
```